# Error accessing an element in the arrarylist

Tags: java, arraylist, comparator

```
public  void dataAnalytics()
{
  double sum=0;  
  double i=0;
  double minage=20;
  double maxage=20;

    System.out.println("dataAnalytics for the Rural region");

    for (Record ee :RList)
    {
      sum=sum+Double.valueOf(ee.getIncome());
      i++;
     }

     ageComparator sc = new ageComparator();
     Collections.sort(RList, sc);

     maxage = (RList[0]).getAge();
     minage = (RList[ records.length - 1]).getAge();


     System.out.println("Average income for the Rural region is : $"+sum/i);
     System.out.println("Min age  for the Rural region is : "+minage);
     System.out.println("Max age for the Rural region is : "+maxage);

}
```

I am trying to access a variable in the first object of the array and the last object of the arrayList which will give me the min age and max age from the arraylist. This line is giving me the eror::

```
maxage = (RList[0]).getAge();
minage = (RList[ records.length - 1]).getAge();
```

any ideas/

Comment: array required, but java.util.ArrayList<mp2test.Record> found

Comment: is the code for passing the values to min and max age right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array list is not indexed using the square braces but using getters, try:

```
RList.get(0).getAge();
Rlist.get(RList.size()-1).getAge();
```

See here for details. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

To use array syntax you can use

```
Rlist.toArray()[0];
```

Comment: one more question , then in which case do we use square braces?

Comment: To declare and array you would use syntax like Record[] records = new Record[10]();

Answer (score 2):

You're using two different variables here.  If you want the last element in `RList` you should be using its length.  Also, use `get` not array syntax.

```
minage = RList.get(RList.size() - 1).getAge();
```

Edit: also, `size()` not `length`.